# JMS Messages in Eclipse and Maven - is there any difference?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, jms

I've created two projects: first sends logs using log4j JMSAppender, second receives them from topic and puts into a file. 
When I compile my project using `Eclipse compiler` everything works OK - I can find logs in created file.

When I compile projects using `Maven` there are no logs. But also there are no errors during compilation, no exceptions and my "welcome messages" (e.g. `System.out.println("Server is ready.");`) are displayed correctly from each main.

Do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: How are you configuring the log4j JMSAppender?  When you package up with Maven, are you turning it on?

Comment: @Dave I put `jndi.properties` and `log4j.properties` in `src` folder. Isn't it enough? Could you please tell me how to "turn it on"?

Comment: Not sure of your exact set up (what folders are source folders in Eclipse and in Maven) so not sure if this will answer your question, but maybe take a look at the location of your `.properties` files. In maven the `src` folder is not a default directory used for source files (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), so that might be a reason why maven is not seeing your logging configuration. Try moving the 2 `.properties` files to be under src/main/resources and see if that works.